# How to load nested XML file data from blob storage into SQL Server using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a nested XML file in which I have data related header and line items. I want to load that data from blob storage to a SQL Server table using Azure Data Factory. If it is a simple XML file then I know in copy activity I can select collection reference to my array object then it will copy data successfully, but I have multiple array objects in the file and I can only define one object for collection reference.

Is there any other way I can load this complex XML file into a SQL Server table?

Comment: It is possible to pass entire XML as a parameter to a stored procedure (SP), and shred it  in that SP via XQuery into related header and line items.

Comment: I prefer using Powershell script to parse xml and then load into SQL Server.

Comment: can you share the sample xml file input and sql output?

Comment: @PratikLad, the sample file that used , can be loaded using simple copy activity as well , My sample file is like below

Comment: <os> <Info> <ID></ID> </Info>
  <o>
    <h> <name></name>
        <PartY><Type>1</Type><address></address><city> <name>/name></City></PartY>
      <PartY><Type>2</Type><address></address><city> <name>/name></City></PartY></h>
    <l> <ShipingID>1</ShipingID> <item> <id>101</id><qty>2</qty><reference> <Type>A</Type> <Value>1</Value></reference>
 <Date> <Shipping></Shipping> <Booking></Booking></Date> </item>
     <item> <id>102</id><qty>2</qty><reference> <Type>B</Type> <Value>2</Value></reference>
 <Date> <Shipping></Shipping> <Booking></Booking></Date></item> </l>
  </o></os>@Pratik

Answer (score 0):

To load complex(nested) XML file, you can use Data Flow activity to map correctly multiple collections.

**My sample XML:**

```xml
<orders>
  <order>
    <header>
      <order_id>12345</order_id>
      <customer_name>John Doe</customer_name>
      <order_date>2023-07-28</order_date>
    </header>
    <line_items>
      <item>
        <product_id>101</product_id>
        <product_name>Product A</product_name>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <unit_price>25.99</unit_price>
      </item>
      <item>
        <product_id>102</product_id>
        <product_name>Product B</product_name>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <unit_price>19.95</unit_price>
      </item>
    </line_items>
  </order>
</orders>
```

To flatten multiple array objects, you can use data flow [flatten transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten).

- In Unroll by set your Array objects that need to be flatten.
  [image]

**Data Preview:**
[image]